# Disabling Email Notifications in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, email-notification, access-requests

In a SharePoint site we have 3 owners. on an an access request to SharePoint site all three owners receive email notifications. one of the owner do not want to receive such email notifications.

Is there any solution to disable email notification of user access request for a particular site owner?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to disable notification of particular site owner.

You can only disable notification for all site owners & specify email address for receiving access requests as given below:

[image]